# visual studio code change launch from chrome to lite-server

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, lite-server

I'm trying to launch https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin project in my developing enviroment and I face a problem. 
The ng2-admin project is developed in visual studio code with the following launch.json:

```
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/*",
          "runtimeArgs": [
            "--disable-web-security",
            "--user-data-dir",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
          ],
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
//, ...
      ]
    }
```

Due to our company restriction I can't use chrome browser. So I would like to adapt launch.json to launch the project using lite-server (like in Angular 2 tutorial: https://github.com/angular/quickstart). I tried to modify `package.json` and `launch.json` I but ended up with endless list of errors. Cound you explain how to launch ng2-admin using lite-server?

Comment: Wait, what browser are you using if you can't use Chrome?